# Use recursive function to make subdir

Tags: php, function, loops, mkdir

Given a stop number for example 3. Than it will create a folder and than 2 sub folder in this folder and than 3 subsub folder in each sub folder.

How to use a simple php recursive function to do this?

It's my code and I cannot do it and I have considered this problem for a long time..

```
function mkpath($path,$stop_turn){

    if($stop_turn==1){
      return 0;
    }


    if(!file_exists($path)){
      mkdir($path,0777,false);
    }
    else
      $path=$path.'/'.$stop_turn;

    return mkpath($path,$stop_turn-1);

}

mkpath("1",2);
```

Comment: path, path/1, path/2, path/1/1, path/1/2, path/1/3,path/2/1, path/2/2, path/2/3?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below given snippet will do following thing,

let us assume give path is /1 and $till is 3

it will create a subdirectory 1 in 1

in /1/1 it will create 2 subdirectory named 1 and 2

in /1/1/1 and /1/1/2 it will create three subdirectories named 1 2 3.

```
function mkpath($path, $till, $count = 1) {
    if($count > $till)
        return ;
    for($i = 1; $i<=$count; $i++ ) {
        $newPath = $path."$i";
        if(!file_exists($newPath)){
            mkdir($newPath,0777,false);
        }
        mkpath($newPath."/", $till, $count + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You perfectly solved this problem which make me crazy for almost 2 hours! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There should be a mkdir commandline argument ( /s or /p) to create all missing subdirectories in mkdir path argument

Comment: with 3rd param in mkdir as true - *recursive
Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the pathname.* He really should create just leaf dirs